# Setting up Rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm a beginner in Ruby, following "[Creating a New Rails Project](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project)".

But I can't start the server. I tried:

1. running `rails server` but got:

   ```
   Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data <>= 0> x86-mingw32' in the gems available on the machine. 
   Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
   ```
2. running `bundle install` but got:

   ```
   An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2'' succeeds before bundling.
   ```
3. `gem 'tzinfo-data'` but got:

   ```
   Unknown command tzinfo-data
   ```
4. `gem install tzinfo-data`:

   ```
   Could not find a valid gem 'tzinfo-data' <>= 0>, here is why:
   Unable to download data from...
   ```

I have Windows 8.1. 64-bit

---

`tzinfo-data` was resolved with a `cacert.pem` file following the guide in the accepted answer. Today I am trying to install `bootstrap-sass` gem file. Do I need an another .pem file?

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/boots
trap-sass-3.3.1.0.gem)
An error occurred while installing bootstrap-sass (3.3.1.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bootstrap-sass -v '3.3.1.0'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

Comment: Did you try `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'`? Does that give an error?

Comment: @lurker Yes, it gives the same error as gem install tzinfo-data, except instead of 0 is 10.4.2

Comment: One of the first directions was, `gem install rails`. Did that go OK without an error? And what's the rest of the error message you see from the `gem install tzinfo-data`? From... where?

Comment: @lurker That gives the same type of error - Could not find a valid gem [...]

What is strange, that I had Rails 4.1 (or 4.0.1 correct me if I'm wrong) but now that I started typing aforementioned commands now it shows the same error as for rails server command. See that in the post.

Comment: @lurker The rest of the error is this --> ... h'ttps://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed ( h'ttps://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Could you give us a trace that bundle install returns and the OS type where you trying to work with rails

Comment: @freeze C:\Sites\blog>bundle install
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
///
Windows 8.1

Comment: Ok, You just killed my hope to help you :) That is Windows, dude. Move in any other OS like *nix or MacOS and you will be happy

Comment: @freeze ;( Thanks, man. I was afraid of that. But isn't there a way to make it work for the old grandpa called Windows?

Comment: Actually I think it is, but all of my tries to make it work on windows was failed. Actually there was 2 tries in my life. But when you move on linux your life will be much easier, and if you move on macos you will be most happier.

Comment: @freeze Oh the pain... :D Actually, sad but it was time for me to move to MacOS.

Comment: Just curious, do you perhaps have a firewall issue while trying to reach gem repository?  Are you able to open https://rubygems.org

Comment: @Vlad not one of which I am aware. Simply the link? Yes, of course.

Comment: Cool, looks like you got your solution.  :)

Comment: @Vlad Yeah, sure did. Still thanks to others trying to help. :)

Comment: Glad you're successful. Can you tell me how to improve the answer? This SSL question is being asked a *lot* this month, and any info you can provide about your Windows setup that helps will help many developers. Thanks! (I'm joelparkerhenderson @ gmail.com)

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson What kind of info would be helpful? 

The main things I know are--> OS:Windows 8.1 PRO; 64-bit;

Comment: Where you put the cert (and why there)? How you added it to the control panel (if you did)? Anything in my answer that could make it easier for the next person?

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson I put the cacert.pem file in the directory as in the answer because the SSL certificate failure was connected particularly with failing to launch  `rails server`. For possible future notices/// 
As the file opens up in text, I added .gz ending to the hyperlink to download the file. Also I could press Ctrl+S and change the file type. /// I did not add cacert.pem to the control panel.  

I reloaded command prompt and pasted in the command line which you provided. (C:\Sites> {your command line}) /// Then typed `bundle install` in command prompt

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson But that's really struggling to make your answer better. For the most part, you might be more precise with where to paste the command line i.e. can it be pasted with a directory showing on the command line C:\Sites\blog> or C:\Sites> or it does not matter.

But all in all, it's a great answer and solves the issue 100%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a common SSL issue.

You will see this error message:

```
certificate verify failed
```

The error message is because your system needs a new SSL certificate.

Here's information about it:

http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

On Windows:

Try upgrading your SSL certificates.

1. Download http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.
2. Save this file anywhere you want, such as:

   ```
   C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
   ```
3. On the command line, tell Ruby where to find the cert file, such as:

   ```
   set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem
   ```
4. Retry the gem installation.
5. If it works, that's great. If you want this to work with every project on your system, and also survive rebooting, then you can make the cert file permanent by adding the cert system-wide. To do this, use your Windows control panel.

Credit and more info: https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: What do you mean by - Tell Ruby where to find the cert file?

I mean where should I paste the command? I currently have opened Command Prompt with ruby and it starts with --> C:\Sites>

Comment: Oh, yes! I typed - bundle install - after doing what you said and now it is installing. I'll update you if some additional errors occur. Thank you!

Comment: And the rails server command also worked now. Thank you alot!

Comment: Thanks. I'm surpised - typically the one cacert.pem solves this for the whole system. 1. Are you on the same system? 2. If so, are you using the same shell window? 3. What happens if you try the "set ..." command again, then try installing? 4. Did you add the cert file to your control panel? 5. If so, can you reboot the system and try installing?

Comment: Yes, I am on the same system. What is the shell window? I can say that I did not change anything in the past days. Hmm, it seems that every new project needs the path to `cacert.pem` file set again. Because now everything worked fine. Once again thank you! --- Now, this is what you should add to your answer, that every new project needs the path to the `cacert file` set again.

Comment: Good. Glad it works. The shell window is a generic term for whatever you're typing in, such as a black CMD.exe window, or cygwin, etc. Did you add the cert file to your control panel?

Comment: Oh, I'll note that. Thanks! No, did not add. Is there any reason to add `cacert.pem` to the control panel because it seems to work fine without it.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, it seems I did not read the 5. point completely. I'll add it to my system as you suggested.